# apex:relatedList pageSize works in sandbox, but not production

Tags: visualforce, related-list

I just deployed a custom account page from our sandbox to production instances. One the changes involved was to use

`<apex:detail id="Account" relatedList="false"/>`

and then reconstruct all of the related lists individually, for various reasons. One of them was so that we can control the number of lines returned for each list, using the pageSize attribute

```
<apex:relatedList list="Contracts" rendered="true" pageSize="5" />
```

This worked as expected in sandbox, but isn't working in production. It will allow for a higher number than the default, but not lower.

Is there something else which controls related list behaviour that I'm not aware of?

Edit: To clarify, our lists in production currently default to around 50, though it's not consistent between objects

Answer (score 0):

page size value is by default 5 if not specified anything, so try decrease the number and I am sure that will work.

Refer to this article here .

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_relatedList.htm

Comment: Currently the lists on our page vary in size, some show 32, some 45 etc. This was the case before deployment (and part of the push for it) and is still the case now.

Comment: you are trying to define page size as 5 here aren't you ?<apex:relatedList list="Contracts" rendered="true" pageSize="5" />

Comment: I am, yes. However, the page is not responding to 5, 4, or anything less than whatever it currently shows for that object. If I set page size as more than what is being displayed (say 30 when a list is showing 25) then it will reflect that change. This is what leads me to conclude that these defaults are being defined elsewhere and overriding my changes.